# Css background propagated to the header

Tags: css, background-image

The `background-image` begins from the `section`, which means the `header` part is blank (doesn't have the image). However, with the addition of the CSS, the `background-image` propagated to the `header`! Can anyone explain what happened?

HTML:

```
<body>
  <!-- Forked from a template on Tutorialzine: https://tutorialzine.com/2016/06/freebie-landing-page-template-with-flexbox -->
  <header>
    <h2><a href="#">Mountain Travel</a></h2>
    <nav>
      <li class="new"><a href="#">Tours</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <section class="hero">
    <div class="background-image" style="background-image: url(assets/img/main.jpg);"></div>
    <div class="hero-content-area">
      <h1>Mountain Travel</h1>
      <h3>Unmissable Adventure Tours Around The World</h3>
      <span class="old"><a href="#" class="btn">Contact Us Now</a></span>
    </div>
  </section>

</body>
```

CSS:

```css
header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set the `position` of an element to `absolute` it removes it from the normal document flow. This means that the browser won't take its dimensions into account when placing subsequent content. In this case, when the `header` element collapses in this way the `.hero` element is being moved up the page to render over the top of the content of the `header` element.